# How do I create a dynamic array for a google combo chart with a database?

Tags: php, arrays, google-visualization

I am trying to make a combo chart (googlecharts) which needs to be dynamic corresponding to database data.

I got a database table called planning, which has the user_id, project_id and status of the planning.
What I want to do is make a combo chart which will show the number of projects (status) per week for every employee.

So the numbers that are hardcoded in the array are the numbers I want to make variable with the database data, but I have no idea how to begin building the array.

I am using Laravel(Eloquent) if you are wondering what I am doing with the Models.

```
            $fd = Input::get('fd');
            $ld = Input::get('ld');
            $pid = Input::get('pid');
            $getPlanning = Planning::whereBetween('date', array($fd, $ld))->where('project_id', $pid)->get();
            $getEmployees = (Project::find($pid)->users);
            $employees[] = 'Days';

            foreach($getEmployees as $employee)
            {
                $employees[] = $employee->firstname.' '.$employee->middlename.' '.$employee->lastname;
            }

            for($i=0; $i<7; $i++)
            {
                $dates[$i] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fd. ' + '.$i.' day'));
            }

            foreach($getPlanning as $v)
            {
                $planning[] = [$v->user_id => $v->status];
            }

            for($j=0; $j<count($employees); $j++)
            {

            }

            $table = array(
                $employees,
                [$dates[0], 0, 5, 9, 4, 6, 7],
                [$dates[1], 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9],
                [$dates[2], 1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7],
                [$dates[3], 3, 7, 8, 4, 6, 7],
                [$dates[4], 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9],
                [$dates[5], 3, 9, 9, 1, 2, 3],
                [$dates[6], 3, 9, 9, 3, 4, 5]
            );

        return $getPlanning;
```

Comment: What does each number after the date represent? What determines the order?

Comment: The number after the date is the height of the chart bar that for each employee. I just hardcoded that in and the mission was to make that array dynamically.